# R patterns in sub function

Tags: r

I want to replace space with tab in a text variable.

For example something like:

```
space <- "123 4 56 789"
tab <- sub("[[:space:]]+$", "[[:space:]]+$", x)
print(tab)
```

Comment: Some friendly advice: you've asked 7 questions and received some good answers. If an answer solves your problem, many here consider it polite to accept that answer (clicking on the check mark next to so that it turns green). Doing this greatly increases the value of the questions here by signaling to future viewers which answer solved your problem.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand I had to do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this work?

```
x <- "123 4    56 789"
x <- gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", x) #eliminate trailing and leading spaces
tab <- gsub(" +", "\t", x, ) #sub out spaces between for \t
cat(tab)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use gsub function like this:

```
gsub(' ', '\t', x)
```